# Evaluate $\int \frac{2x\ln(x)-x}{\ln^2(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral: $$\int \frac{2x\ln(x)-x}{\ln^2(x)} dx$$

So far I only really know U-sub and some basic integrals, but I don't know what to sub in. Any hints please

Comment: Try computing the derivative of $\frac{x^2}{\log x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

This integral has the form
$\displaystyle\int\left(\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\right)' \mathrm d x$.